# jScrollPane bug: scrolls vertically with mousewheel fine, but also scrolls 1px horizontally

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, mousewheel

(FYI, the bug occurs on [the official demos](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html) as well as my own demos and reacts the same using FF4, Safari4, and IE8 on WinXP.)

- When I use the jquery.mousewheel.js plugin (v3.0.4) and scroll using the mousewheel, it scrolls vertically as expected. However, it simultaneously scrolls one pixel right-to-left every time the mousewheel is spun. So if I scroll down a couple paragraphs and back up, the left position of div.jspPane can sometimes be -[whatever]px to the left ([whatever] increasing depending on how much I scroll.)
- When I use the arrow keys on my keyboard to scroll, it scrolls correctly and as expected.
- It also works correctly when I click on one of the a.jspArrow's or anywhere on a div.jspTrack.

The problem only seems to be when using the mousewheel. Can anyone replicate this behavior, or is it just me? Please let me know if you can't and I'll gladly post a video. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue and there is a suggested fix waiting to be pulled:

https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane/pull/75

I'll integrate it into the plugin (I'm the author of jScrollPane) ASAP

Comment: That's great news. Thanks!
Love your plugin, btw. I thought it was an odd omission to not have something like this as part of jQuery UI (the "slider" scrollbar demo is really buggy). Thanks again for all your work.